# How to add a fixed value in a listbox containing binded items

Tags: c#, binding, listbox

I've an enumerable providing a variable data set of values. The values are generated while runtime from the user.

These values are bound to an ItemsSource of a ListBox

```
public IEnumerable<string> Items
{
  get { return list; } // list is here a dummy; it does not actually exists
}

listbox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = Items });
```

Now I want to add one fixed item at the beginning. But e.g. `lb.Items.Add("abc");` will break runtime. Same for the insert method.

```
// listbox.Items.Add("abc");
// listbox.Items.Insert(0, "abc");
```

How do I add a fixed item at the beginning?

Comment: break = you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Concat` if you're bound to an `IEnumerable<string>`

```
listbox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, 
  new Binding { Source = new[] { "abc" }.Concat(Items) });
```

Equally, if it's a `List<string>` that you're binding to - use `Insert` to add the fixed item at the head after you've built it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, didn't know that it could be that simple:)

Comment: Do you have also an idea what I've to do if I like to create the Binding with `new Binding("Items")`.

Comment: If you mean something like the [`Binding(string, object, string) constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wkkxwcz.aspx) then you should be able to pass `new[] { "abc" }.Concat(Items)` as the second parameter.  You might need to add `.ToArray()` to the end of it though - try it without first and see if that works.

Comment: Ah I think I see - you want to take the string `"Items"` and resolve it to the property on the form?  I'd ask a separate question about that :)

Comment: Yep, that's what I want to do. Items should be the PropertyPath, instead of Source as in my first approach. :)